# AWS Lambda function with lots of scheduled events

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, scheduled-tasks, aws-lambda

I’ve created a Dynamodb table that will be populated with hostnames that I want to ping using AWS Lambda. Every time a new entry is added to this Dynamodb table, I want a new scheduled job to be added to a lambda function for the specified hostname. For example, if I have 100 hostnames in my dynamodb table, I would have 100 scheduled jobs at various intervals executing the lambda function. Is there a way to execute this?

Comment: Are you referring to scheduling lambda or triggering lambda?

Comment: @helloV scheduling lambda

Comment: Unless you want to schedule it for a particular reason, you should consider triggering it. Less work for you.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions can be triggered by many different [event sources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html), including direct invocation via an API call and also from a schedule within [Amazon CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html).

It appears that your goal is:

- At a regular time period
- For each entry in a given DynamoDB table
- Execute a Lambda function

Rather than creating 100 schedules for 100 entries, you could just create a single entry:

- When the **schedule** fires...
- Run a Lambda function that **reads the table**
- For each entry in the table, call a ***new Lambda function***, passing in the desired hostname that was retrieved from the database

This way, you only require **one schedule** that will automatically fire off other tasks based upon the number of entries in the database table.

Please note that there is a default limit of **100 concurrent Lambda functions**. So, if your function takes 0.5 seconds to run, only 200 functions would run per second.